# Split string with multiple delimiter including delimiters

Tags: java, regex, stringtokenizer

I would like to split a string using multiple character delimiters, but I also want to store delimiters. My delimiters are `()+-*/`

So for example, if I had a string

`26+78(12*23)-16`

I want to get

```
26

+

78

(

12

*

23

)

-

16
```

each line as a separate array element.

I think you can not use split function to achieve this. However, my trial with string-tokenizer also failed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Consider using regular expressions.

Comment: One more way if you consider using UTF-8 char encoding.

Comment: if it was `c#` it would have been `(?=([()*+-]))`..but it's java..:P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't answer if it wasn't saturday night here:

```
    String s1 = "26+78(12*23)-16";
    for(String s: s1.split("(?<=[()+*/-])|(?=[()+*/-])")){
        System.out.println(">> " + s);
    }
```

gives:

```
>> 26
>> +
>> 78
>> (
>> 12
>> *
>> 23
>> )
>> -
>> 16
```