# split a string using multiple delimiters (including delimiters) in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which I input as follows

```
using namespace std;

string s;
getline(cin, s);
```

I input

> a.b~c.d

I want to split the string at `.` and `~` but also want to store the delimiters. The split elements will be stored in a vector.

Final output should look like this

```
a
.
b
~
c
.
d
```

I saw a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894724/split-string-with-multiple-delimiter-including-delimiters) but it was in java.

How do I achieve this in c++?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621727/split-a-string-into-words-by-multiple-delimiters) is close but won't store the delimiters. Should be easy enough to adapt.

Comment: @–user4581301 I saw many similar questions but the solutions did not include delimiters in the output. As I indicated above, there is a soln in Java. However, I want to achieve this in c++

Comment: We need a proper minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is copied verbatim from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7621814/8372853) except for the commented lines:

```
std::stringstream stringStream(inputString);
std::string line;
while(std::getline(stringStream, line)) 
{
    std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
    while ((pos = line.find_first_of(".~", prev)) != std::string::npos)  // only look for . and ~
    {
        if (pos > prev)
            wordVector.push_back(line.substr(prev, pos-prev));
        wordVector.push_back(line.substr(pos, 1));               // add delimiter 
        prev = pos+1;
    }
    if (prev < line.length())
        wordVector.push_back(line.substr(prev, std::string::npos));
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but the basic idea is you want to store the delimiter character in the result as well.